# Protractor failing on Windows with "cannot call method 'forEach' of null"

Tags: angularjs, protractor

If you run the [Angular Phone Catalog Tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) on Windows right now, you get this error:

```
d:\dev\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium
net\index.js:48
interfaces[key].forEach(function(ipAddress) {
                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of null
at getAddress
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically:
selenium-webdriver is intentionally only looking at darwin and linux systems to find the local loopback address (typically 127.0.0.1). So it's not working on windows.

The workaround is to change the "chromeOnly" setting in test/protractor-conf.js from true to false:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  chromeDriver: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\selenium',

 chromeOnly: false,  <-- this option was "true"
```

This  is  condensed  from  the  work  at

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/906

Comment: The seleniumAddress was also required for me.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this same issue, on windows 7 64bit & windows 7 32bit,

The chromeOnyl=true didn't work for me, I solved the issue by updating the version of protractor and karma in the package.json to the latest versions and explicitly add karma-cli dependency

Guessing it must be a bug in protractor on windows 7 resolve in the latest version.

->

```
"karma": "^0.12.16",
"karma-cli": "^0.0.4",
"protractor": "^1.0.0-rc",
```

eg so package json was

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.12.16",
    "karma-cli": "^0.0.4",
    "protractor": "^1.0.0-rc",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",

    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -p 8000",

    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",

    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",

    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",

    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

there's a bug issue ticket here -> https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/176

hope this helps you

cheers

Zap